# How to read an object from managedObjectContext in Core Data ( Xcode )

Tags: core-data, nsarraycontroller, nspersistentdocument, managedobjectcontext

I have a program that gets some numbers in a tableView . I have a Core Data based program that has an entity with some attributes and could bind the columns of the tableview to those attributes.
Now I want to have the sum of each column , but couldn't find how I can read each data in rows to add them.
I used

> NSString* S= [self.managedObjectContext   valueAtIndex:1 inPropertyWithKey:@"aColumnName" ];

but I receive this error:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.

Can anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I found it . I should have used @"selection.aColumnName"